# Google Maps Geo Location Store Locator Demo link not displaying in ie11

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Geo Location Store Locator Demo link not displaying in IE11

http://storage.googleapis.com/gmaps-store-locators/index.html,

- it displays in chrome
- the url is not currently added to the view compatability settings
- IE version is 11.611
- The notes say it the current APi version supports ie10 & 11
- windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from [Google Maps Help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3118069?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612):

> If you use Internet Explorer to view Google Maps, you might have some
>   display problems. Internet Explorer has Compatibility View, a feature
>   that affects how Maps may be displayed. To fix this, you can turn off
>   Compatibility View.

You can follow the steps from link and make sure that you have latest Windows updates and latest version of Internet Explorer.